# I want to have a progress bar indicating how much data has been downloaded while downloading the file in .net core API

Tags: .net, api, download

I tried the below code but this is not showing the progress bar.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/testDownloadFile")]
    public IActionResult DownloadFile([FromQuery] string filename)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot\\test", filename);
        var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

        return File(stream, "application/octect-stream", filename);

    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.